# Error Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, debugging

I'm trying to make an application that reads a file and writes the sum of the numbers, the average, the number of numbers in the file, but I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
t java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at TestGradesAnalysis.main(TestGradesAnalysis.java:30)
Java Result: 1
```

Can you help me fix the error?

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.*;

public class TestGradesAnalysis {

     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("File.dat"));
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double max = 0;
        double min = 0;

        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            sum = sum + in.nextInt();
            count++;
            if (in.nextDouble() > max) {
                max = in.nextDouble();

            }
            if (min > in.nextDouble()) {
                min = in.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        double average = sum / count;

        outFile.println("average is" + average);
        outFile.println("max is" + max);
        outFile.println("min is " + min);
        outFile.println("number of grades is" + count);

    }
```

This is my code

These are the contents of the File.dat

28 28 28 2008 510
September 89, 2116

Comment: Just for the completeness of the question - could you please post an input file (myDataFile.dat) example as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `while` loop you are calling `nextDouble()` multiple times. Meaning that even if `hasNextDouble()` is true, you advance several fields in one iteration a probably try to parse the `September` String as double at some point.

The solution would be to read the value once in every iteration and storing it in a variable.

```
while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
    double current = in.nextDouble();
    sum = sum + current;
    count++;

   if (current > max) {
       max = current;
   }
   if (min > current) {
       min = current;
   }
}
```

Comment: After doing that, I cannot print to the file

Comment: How can I program java to create a text file and then print to that text file?

Comment: You have to call `outFile.flush()` as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27207609).

Comment: @ValterStrods how would I find the minimum value in the set of integers?

Comment: @CrazyRaisans `max = Double.MIN_VALUE` and `min = Double.MAX_VALUE` should do the trick.

Comment: @CrazyRaisans Along with `double sum = 0` and `int count = 0`, you should set `double max = Double.MIN_VALUE` and `double min = Double.MAX_VALUE`. Are you saying that is not working?

Comment: @ValterStrods but it's counter intutitive to set max to Double.MIN_VALUE.. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @CrazyRaisans It does seem rather logical. Let's take the example of the `min` value as it is going to be the one affected here. In your original example `min` starts out as 0. That is a _rather_ low value for a sequence where all the elements are positive numbers as during the following checks, you will not encounter a number that is smaller than `min`. As no numbers are smaller, the value doesn't get changed and is left at 0. We work around this by ensuring that the values we work with are always smaller than the initial value (MAX_VALUE). Same applies to `max`, just the other way around.

Comment: @CrazyRaisans Additionally, you could use the wrapper class of double and set the initial value as `null`, then adding a pair of cases to check later down the line, but I would suggest against that in this example just in case the input data expands further since autoboxing and unboxing will have a negative performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going wrong, but we start by focusing on the original question about the reported failure.

## Misuse of Scanner.next()

The `Scanner.next*()` methods check the next token. This means that when you call them multiple times in your while loop, you will advance the list faster than what you probably want. We can fix this by calling it once at the start of the loop and holding on to the value.

## Stopping at "April"

I am not completely sure of your requirements so I am not even sure if this needs to be fixed or what behaviour would be expected, but keep in mind the number reading from the input file will stop at the word "April". This is due for it checking whether there are any doubles (floating point numbers) coming up. That is false for a word/string (such as "April"). You could make the code advance by checking the generic hasNext() in combination with next() for a set amount of times if you so desire.

## Missing output in the output file

You may or may not miss out on any output. The file will get created rather fast, but the writing might not happen. This is caused then by the program finishing before the writer can flush the stream. You should call [PrintWriter.flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush--) after doing your println calls to inform the system it should flush the stream.

From the [documentation for OutputStream.flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--):

> The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination.

## The output file may not be in the correct directory

As you create the FileWriter with just a filename, I am not fully sure if you want to create it at the current working directory or not. I presume it is unintentional, in which case the filename provided should be `dir + "/myDataFile.dat"` instead.

## Faulty minimum/maximum output values

You should set `max` as [Double.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) and `min` as [Double.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE) when initializing those values. You will already see the minimum value not being set properly in your example - this is caused by the minimum value being 0 all the time already. You would see the maximum value not being set properly with your current code all of a sudden if all your values were actually negative (lower than 0).